# Usar método de controller em rota com Slim

Tags: php, slim

Tenho um *controller* chamado `CardController` com vários métodos dentro dele, porem preciso passar via parâmetro alguns dados para esses métodos.
Atualmente eu só consigo acessar os métodos diretamente como o segundo exemplo

```
$app->group('/v1', function() {

    /**
     * Dentro de v1, o recurso /card
     */
    $this->group('/card', function($app) {
        $this->get('', function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app){
            //chamar a funcao getcard do controller aqui passando parametros
        });

        $this->post('', '\App\v1\Controllers\CardController:getcard'); //só consigo chamar assim
```

Comment: Confuso. Tem como explicar o problema com texto, não sendo comentários no código?

Comment: Tentei explicar melhor no texto

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta ficou um pouco confusa, mas vou tentar ajudar com base no que entendi.

Você pode criar um controller com o método `__invoke()` e receber os objetos `$request` e `$responde` neste método. Depois você passa esse controller criado no lugar da função anônima que você declarou como parâmetro do método `$this->get()`.

Para poder passar os dados para os métodos, você vai ter que repassar eles como parâmetros. Lembrando que apenas um método é executado em um controller para uma determinada rota. O outros métodos serão chamados de dentro do controller, ou então serão associados com outras rotas.

Comment: Troquei os meus parametros paradao para   public function getcard(Request $request,Response $response, $args) e funcionou